# Firebug - where is the "stop loading" on the network panel

Tags: firebug, loading

Stupid question. I wish to stop the Network Panel on firebug from loading after certain time or certain number of requests. Much like Google Chrome dev tools.

If I cant stop the network panel from loading then the page loads automatic slider/carousel images that pumps up my page weight - and makes me look bad in front of my sponsor.

Where is it - Please?

I use Firebug 2.0.13

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has no UI for stopping the recording of network requests, though there is the preference [`extensions.firebug.net.logLimit`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firebug_Preferences#net.logLimit), which allows you to control how many requests are displayed (default value is 500). You can change this preference within [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

When the limit is reached you see the following message:
[image: Network request log limit reached]

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. While this could help, it is not easy / scalable for the 40+ web pages stats that I need to collect for my website. Anyways thanks again.

Comment: I didn't say it's easy, but that is what Firebug offers and what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for taking the time. Sure, lets leave it at "that's what firebug offers". Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should normally react to an answer on Stack Overflow by up- or downvoting or accepting it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I will surel ydo it, as soon as I've gained enough points to upvote.